# How to center in JTable cell a value?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to center a value in `JTable` cell?  I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: you must be using some other component inside the cell, example JLabel so it would have it's alignment properties.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to customize the renderer. To center the first column you can do:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
```

To center all columns with String data you can do:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me. JLabel.RIGHT aligns right, JLabel.LEFT aligns left, but if I use JLabel.CENTER it aligns right again. Why would it be?

Comment: @nawara, JTableHeader has its own renderer.

Comment: Though it is an old post, but still it should be better. You should use `SwingConstants.CENTER` rather than `JLabel.CENTER`. Though, `JLabel.CENTER' is also referring to `SwingConstants.CENTER`, it will be much more concise to use generic constant class, rather than `JLabel` which is out of context in this scenario.

Comment: Why doesn't `((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class)).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);` work instead of your second piece of code? -- I've tried it, it doesn't work, I don't know why. No errors, it just remains uncentered. It seems to me this one liner should work. Your code works, of course.

Comment: I ask the above question because the code:
`((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);`... does work for the table header. As mention in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493428/693927).

Comment: @PimpTrizkit, changing the alignment of the default renderer works fine for me. I can only guess you have some other code that resets the renderer?

Comment: @camickr - I cant think of what it would be. I got a few lines of code. `JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();JTable jt = new JTable(new MyTModel(dataArray, colNames)); ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) jt.getDefaultRenderer(Integer.class)).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); sp.setViewportView(jt); myTPane.addTab("# "+x,sp);` -- I make the table with my custom model, adjust it, set the scroll pane viewport, add scroll pane to tab. And its not centered.  Data is ints.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit, create a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem and then post a question on the forum.

Comment: Wanted to post an observation, using Object.class instead of String.class needs to be used if the data is in a TableModel

Comment: @Ironluca *if the data is in a TableModel* - all data is in a TableModel. The default Implementation of the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel, simply returns Object.class, so you would be correct. However it is standard to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method to return the proper class of the column so the appropriate renderer can be used.

Comment: For me, `Object.class` instead of `String.class` worked (thank you @Ironluca ). Not sure why though.

Answer (score 9):

Another good way to center all columns is with a loop:

```
 for(int x=0;x<numberofcols;x++){
         table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class JTableUtilities
{
    public static void setCellsAlignment(JTable table, int alignment)
    {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);

        TableModel tableModel = table.getModel();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < tableModel.getColumnCount(); columnIndex++)
        {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
JTableUtilities.setCellsAlignment(table, SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to align a single cell depending on the value of another cell. If cell X was NULL, then cell Y should be RIGHT aligned. Else, cell Y should be LEFT aligned.

I found this solution really helpful. It consists on creating a custom Render, extending DefaultTableCellRender.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

@Override
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column){
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    MyTableModel mtm = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
    switch(column){
        case Y : 
            if(mla.getValueAt(row,X)!=null)
                setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            else
                setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            break;
     }
    return this;
   }

 }
```

After that, just create a new instance of MyRender and set it to column Y, in this case. I do this when I load the information on the table.

```
MyRender render = new MyRender();
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(Y).setCellRender(render);
```

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 2):

```
((DefaultTableCellRenderer) jTable1.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
            .setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); // header to center
```

This code header center jtable

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer rendar = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    rendar.setHorizontalAlignment(jLabel1.CENTER);

    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(rendar);
```

this code to column center

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `JLabel.CENTER`, you can use `SwingConstants.CENTER`.

Comment: that's the exact same ;-)