# How to center content of JTable Headers at Nimbus Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, nimbus, jtableheader

How can i center the content of JTable Header which has a nimbus look and feel? I tried to use DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer, but it look like this;

[image: JTable Header with Nimbus Look and Feel]

is there any way to make them all look like PARENT_ID column's and centered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493369/jtable-right-align-header/7494597#7494597) shows one approach. By using the table header's `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, it minimizes the impact on the UI delegate's appearance.