# I would like to add a right-padding to a JTable column, is it possible?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to add right cell-padding to a column in my JTable, how do I do it?

I tried searching online but I can't seem to find a definitive answer for this.

I hope someone can help me.

Regards,
Chad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [custom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) `TableCellRenderer`, and specify `setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT)`. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164751/230513) that illustrates `JLabel.CENTER`.

Addendum: *My problem is padding and not alignment*.

If you want the padding *inside* the cell, rather than *between* cells, you can use a border in the renderer, as @Guillaume Polet suggests. Note that the border can be asymmetric; the example below pads only on the right.

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5));
```

Comment: Hi @trashgod But my problem is padding and not alignment. Could the cell padding be also adjusted using a custom TableCellRenderer?

Comment: @Chad Yes, simply specify `setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));`

Comment: I've elaborated above on @Guillaume Polet's suggestion.

Comment: @pstanton: Can you change the [`HeaderRenderer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7494597/230513)?

Comment: thanks @trashgod just figured that part out too. swing is like a jigsaw puzzle sometimes.

Answer (score 11):

A slightly enhanced version of @trashgod's correct answer is to compound the border with the padding: doing so guarantees that the default borders (f.i. the focus indicator) are not lost:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10);
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                row, column);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(getBorder(), padding));
        return this;
    }

};
```

Or use [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net)' JXTable and decorate the renderer with a Highlighter:

```
BorderHighlighter hl = new BorderHighlighter(
    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
hl.setInner(true);
table.addHighlighter(hl);
```

Answer (score 4):

Give a try with setInternalcellSpacing(Dimension d) of JTable.This will set spaces in both sides.If you strictly want to have it in one side use a renderer as [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2100887)

Comment: What is `setInternalSpacing`?

Comment: @trashgod He probably meant `javax.swing.JTable.setIntercellSpacing(Dimension)`

Comment: yes I meant javax.swing.JTable.setIntercellSpacing(Dimension)  which Sets the rowMargin and the columnMargin ( the height and width of the space between cells )