# Add cellpadding to a Java JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to implement a Swing JTable. I followed the tuorial on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple

I want the table cell's not to be editable (this works) and I want the table cells to have more padding to it's borders. Like cellpadding in HTML.

This is part of my code and the cellpadding thing doesn't work.

```
class BoardTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15,15,15,15));
        return this;
    }
}

String[] columnNames = {"Datei",
        "Zeile",
        "Zeichen",
        "Fehler", "test"};

Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4430174981226468686L;

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return false;
    }};

table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new BoardTableCellRenderer());
```

`table` is placed on a `JScrollPane`. The table is displayed, the cells are not editable but the cellpadding is not applied!

Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You can try three things.  You can try supplying a custom cell renderer that has an `EmptyBorder` applied to it, for every column, a cell editor doing the same thing and/or change the row height property of the table

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17188521/230513).

Comment: As per OP's comment in tenorsax's answer, it **appears** that in fact you can't use this border technique to change the top/bottom padding.  If so you have two options: row height and/or setIntercellSpacing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default implementation of `getColumnClass()` in `DefaultTableModel` which is used by `JTable` (by default) returns `Object.class`. That is the reason `BoardTableCellRenderer` is not used, as you're setting it up for columns with `String.class`.

You may override `getColumnClass`. Or in case of this sample, replace:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new BoardTableCellRenderer());
```

with:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new BoardTableCellRenderer());
```

to see the effect of `BoardTableCellRenderer`.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of worked... However, the 15px Border within the custom `BoardTableCellRenderer()` did only render `left/right` padding and not `top/bottom`. Fot top/bottom I had to add `setRowHeight(25)` on the JTable itself...