# Modifying uitable column header alignment?

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I'm updating my generic data manipulation GUI and I thought I would make use of a `uitable` instead of a `uicontrol` listbox to display the path(s) and filename(s) of the loaded files. I noticed the column headers are centered by default, and I can't seem to figure out how to left align them if the filename is longer than the width of the table. I checked the properties returned by `get` and poked around with [`findjobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) but didn't find anything obvious. My attempt to use an html string was also unsuccessful.

Am I missing something obvious?

Sample code:

```
function testcode
res = get(0,'ScreenSize');
figdim = [1280 720]; % Main figure size, pixels
handles.mainfig = figure( ...
    'Units', 'Pixels', ...
    'Position', [(res(3) - figdim(1))/2 (res(4) - figdim(2))/2 figdim(1) figdim(2)], ...
    'Name', 'Meep', ...
    'Resize', 'off', ...
    'DockControls', 'off', ...
    'NumberTitle', 'off', ...
    'Toolbar', 'figure' ...
    );
handles.filetable = uitable( ...
    'Parent', handles.mainfig, ...
    'Units', 'normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.038 0.71 0.235 0.1], ...
    'ColumnName', 'File Loaded', ...
    'Data', {'None'} ...
    );
handles.loadfilebtn = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', handles.mainfig, ...
    'Style', 'pushbutton', ...
    'Units', 'normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.075 0.85 0.16 0.07], ...
    'String', 'This is a Button, Click', ...
    'Callback', {@abutton} ...
    );
guidata(handles.mainfig, handles);
end
function abutton(hObject,~)
handles = guidata(hObject);

filepath = 'C:\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\superduperreallylongfilename.fileextension';
set(handles.filetable,'Data',{filepath});
set(handles.filetable,'ColumnWidth',{length(filepath)*5});

test = '<html><left />File Loaded</html>';
set(handles.filetable,'ColumnName',test); % Attempt #1, doesn't work
end
```

Comment: I can't remember when I have seen such a good running minimal example code for a gui question! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest workaround I could think of, is to split table and table-header in two separate uitables. It's a little fiddly to set the position vectors properly, but generally it works like a charm. Important: place the "header-uitable" below (in code first) the "data-table". You save some trouble this way.

```
function testcode
close all
res = get(0,'ScreenSize');
figdim = [1280 720]; % Main figure size, pixels
handles.mainfig = figure( ...
    'Units', 'Pixels', ...
    'Position', [(res(3) - figdim(1))/2 (res(4) - figdim(2))/2 figdim(1) figdim(2)], ...
    'Name', 'Meep', ...
    'Resize', 'off', ...
    'DockControls', 'off', ...
    'NumberTitle', 'off', ...
    'Toolbar', 'figure' ...
    );
handles.tableheader = uitable( ...
    'Parent', handles.mainfig, ...
    'Units', 'normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.038 0.71 0.235 0.1], ...
    'ColumnName', 'File Loaded', ...
    'ColumnWidth', {271} ...
    );
handles.filetable = uitable( ...
    'Parent', handles.mainfig, ...
    'Units', 'normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.038 0.682 0.235 0.1], ...
    'ColumnName', {}, ...
    'Data', {'None'} ...
    );
handles.loadfilebtn = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', handles.mainfig, ...
    'Style', 'pushbutton', ...
    'Units', 'normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.075 0.85 0.16 0.07], ...
    'String', 'This is a Button, Click', ...
    'Callback', {@abutton} ...
    );
guidata(handles.mainfig, handles);
end
function abutton(hObject,~)
handles = guidata(hObject);

filepath = 'C:\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\superduperreallylongfilename.fileextension';
set(handles.filetable,'Data',{filepath});
set(handles.filetable,'ColumnWidth',{length(filepath)*5});

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned `findjobj`, which allows you to get the [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) object behind your table. What you're actually trying to do is change some properties of the [header](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#PageTitle), or [`JTableHeader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html) object. Once you know what you're looking for the solution is easy to find (e.g. this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493369/jtable-right-align-header)).

In summary, put this code at the end of the button callback:

```
function abutton(hObject,~)
%// ....

hTable = handles.filetable;
jScrollpane = findjobj(hTable);
jTable = jScrollpane.getComponent(0).getComponent(0);
%// You can see the list of components using findjobj(hTable).list
%// Part1:
dtcr = javaObject('javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer');
dtcr.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
jTable.getColumn(jTable.getColumnName(0)).setHeaderRenderer(dtcr);
%// Part2:
jRenderer = jTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
jRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
%// Finalization:
jTable.invalidate();

end
```

Clicking the button then results in:

[image: ...the desired result]

Several notes:

1. Here's the documentation of [SwingConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html).
2. The two `Parts` are supposed to be two different solutions, but I noticed that it only works if both are present (I have no explanation for this).
3. I tried setting this in the figure creation function, but that didn't work (I have no explanation for this either).
4. Tested on MATLAB 2014a.

Comment: Though I like this java approach, this solution has a major drawback: if you scroll to the right the header disappears.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Utilizing the existing object is what I was hoping to find but @thewaywewalk brings up a good point. The primary motivation for this is to make the interface more visually appealing and the other answer, while pretty hack-ey, better accomplishes the goal. Thank you both :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk - I agree with you. This is what I understood that the OP wanted (hopefully, after considering the possible alternatives and drawbacks).