# Remove border intersection between JTable and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, jscrollpane

I just added a JScrollPane which has a JTable with headers. The problem is that when the JScrollPane shows a border line also shows. How can I remove it?

I already tried:

```
- JTable.setBorder(null);
- JTable.getTableHeader().setBorder(null);
- JScrollPane.setBorder(null);
- JScrollPane.getViewport().setBorder(null);
```

Foto of the JTable: I want to remove that border line that shows between the headers and JScrollPane

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You may need to supply a custom cell renderer for the table headers

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7494597/230513).

Comment: Isn´t that border a property of JScrollPane?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it was a property of JScrollPane. I just created an emptyBorder.

```
JScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,1,1,1));
```