# JTable, html <center> not working

Tags: html, jtable

II have a Jtable and I am trying to centre align the text in the column headings. When I try and use the html center tags it seems to have no effect.

```
  Object[] columns = {"","<html><center>#<br>&nbsp;","<html><center>Type<br>&nbsp;",
        "<html><center>Shots<br>&nbsp;","<html><center>final<br>score","<html><center>Time<br>Played"};
```

Can you see what I am missing or suggest a simple alternative?

Comment: 1) `<center>` is deprecated. 2) Why do you have multiple `<html>` tags? Is that something required by JTable? Because you would only have one opening and one closing HTML tag in a web page.

Comment: Also, you need to close the `</center>` tag. And yes, it has [been deprecated since HTML 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: Will it not even work in my own java app?

Comment: Yes, `renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER)` is shown in the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7494597/230513).