# Set Right Alignment in JTable Column Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I align a text in a cell to right or center in Java Swing
I tried all the ways but it still in the left

this is my code:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.setDataVector(table_info, columns);
table = new JTable(model);
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = 
(DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.RIGHT );
tableScroller = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setRowHeight(40);
tableScroller.setBounds(240, 95, 425, 425);
frame.add(tableScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433602/how-to-center-in-jtable-cell-a-value

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433602/how-to-center-in-jtable-cell-a-value

Comment: Doesn't work...